# Probability of the next generated character sequence

Tags: nlp, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am new to language processing and sorry if this might look a very basic question.

Given a training sequence, for example: "aaabbcddecbbaaaaabbabbbabccddbbcdaaaaaa" (the real sequence is much longer), I can use the recurrent neural networks such as LSTM to learn patterns and dependencies in the sequence to generate next characters (a single character or several characters). For example, feeding a sample sequence "aaabb" will generate "c". It is worth mentioning, that my alphabet contains only 6 ordered characters {a,b,c,d,e,f}

**My question is**: how to compute probability of a particular combination of next characters? For example, given a sequence "aabcdcbbaa" what will be the probability of obtaining "cc" ?

Many thanks in advance!

**UPD**

While writing the question, I realised that the the probability of a combination of the next characters might be computed as a "tensor product" of a single characters. What I mean is: given a test sample, the LSTM outputs a vector (through the softmax function) with probabilities of each character and then these probabilities are converted into a single character (the most probable outcome). For example: the sequence "aabcdcbbaa" will generate a 6-dim vector **p1** = (0.1,  0.07, 0.23, 0.15, 0.31, 0.14) which corresponds to characters (a, b, c, d, e, f). Then by using each of these characters we can compute the probabilities of the next (the second) character **p2**. Then by multiplying these two probability vectors p1Xp2 we can compute the joint probability of obtaining two characters: aa, ab, ac, ad,....

Am I correct?

Comment: From your example I can understand that all events are mutually exclusive and a letter can be chosen more than once. So this means that the probability of selecting a letter equals to P(a)=P(b)=...=P(f)=1/6. Right?

Comment: The probability depends on the patterns in sequence, this is not a markovian process, this is why I'm using RNNs with the memory cells, to learn temporal patterns in data to generate the next character.